# Replacement for preclude meaning to make implausible rather than impossible?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word with similar meaning to preclude, except that the noun acted upon is made implausible or unlikely rather than completely impossible?

Ex: Large stock market gains ____ the possibility that there will be a recession?

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of a synonym for *impede*, or a synonym for *forestall* with a negative connotation?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the verb's object is "the possibility", **reduce** or **lessen**.

Answer (score 0):

I like **gainsay** here; it means

> ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gainsay)) (1) to deny, dispute, or contradict, (2)
>   to speak or act against; oppose;
>
> ([Merriam–Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gainsay)) (1) to declare to be untrue or invalid, (2) contradict, oppose.

**Contradict** and **refute** seem too strong (leaning toward the impossibility side of your question), while **weaken** implies perhaps too much of a causal relationship.